# GET method called twice with code 301 and 200

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a piece of code which uses the RxJava `zip()` operator to simultaneously perform two independent calls to my REST API:

```
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Observable<List<Player>> obs_players = RestAPI.getApi().getService()
                        .getAllPlayers(LoggedUser.getInstance().getToken());

                Observable<List<Game>> obs_games = null;


                // first id corresponds to ALL players
                if (id == 0){

                    obs_games = RestAPI.getApi().getService()
                            .getAllGames();

                }

                // get the player's id
                else{

                    int player_id = (int)liste_players.get((int)id - 1).getId();
                    obs_games = RestAPI.getApi().getService().getGamesSingleUser(player_id);
                }


                // Parallely get all users and required games to be displayed
                Observable<Pair<List<Game>, List<Player>>> obs_combined = null;

                obs_combined.zip(obs_games, obs_players, (l_g, l_p)->
                        new Pair<>(l_g, l_p))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Observer<Pair<List<Game>, List<Player>>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                                Log.d("DBG", "onSubscribe - onItemSelected");

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(@NonNull Pair<List<Game>, List<Player>> listListPair) {

                                Log.d("DBG", "onNext - onItemSelected");


                                // loop over games
                                for (Game g: listListPair.first){
                                    // loop over PlayerInGame
                                    for (PlayerInGame pig: g.getListe_joueurs()){

                                        pig.setPlayer(
                                                Collections2.filter(listListPair.second,
                                                        player-> player.getId()==pig.getPlayer()
                                                                .getId())
                                                        .iterator()
                                                        .next()
                                        );

                                    }

                                }

                                liste_match = listListPair.first;
                                expandable_list_adapter.setData(liste_match);
                                expandable_list_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                                Log.d("", "onError");

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {
                                Log.d("DBG", "onComplete - onItemSelected");


                            }
                        });
```

While it works without raising any error, on the server side, I have noticed that the `GET` method related to `obs_games` is called twice, the second one being a success:

```
[27/Sep/2017 20:49:01] "GET /users/3/games HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[27/Sep/2017 20:49:01] "GET /users/3/games/ HTTP/1.1" 200 537
[27/Sep/2017 20:49:01] "GET /users/ HTTP/1.1" 200 451
```

I have checked that the `onSubscribe()`, `onNext()` and `onComplete()` methods are called once so I do not know where this problem can come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP response code 301 is a redirect.

Your client code is calling the service to get "/users/3/games".  On the server side, something (probably the framework surrounding your code) is recognizing that the path is incorrect.  As a directory, the framework is expecting a trailing "/".

So the server sends back a 301, indicating that what you want has "moved" to "/users/3/games/" (note the trailing "/").

At this point, something on the client side (probably the framework/interface you are using) sees that the address has changed and issues another GET to the server (with the corrected address).

On the 2nd call, the expected server-side function is executed, and responds with a 200 (success).